# What is the sculpture in Kirk’s Quarters — Star Trek VI

Tags: star-trek, art, props, captain-kirk, the-undiscovered-country

Does anyone know anything about this sculpture? Artist? Name of sculpture?

[image]

Comment: Well it's not a Horga'hn. Which is surprising since, well it is Kirk. LOL

Comment: Is that a baby riding an Aldairian porpoise?

Answer (score 6):

It's a statue of a child (probably a boy) riding a dolphin.  [Young people riding on dolphins are a common motif in statuary](https://www.google.com/search?q=sculpture%20of%20boy%20riding%20dolphin&tbm=isch)—although probably more commonly outdoor statuary, where they are often part of fountains or other water features.  However, this particular design does not appear to be based on any particularly famous real-world statues.  (The appearance of the rider look stylistically quite modern, and most famous examples are either classical or Renaissance.)  The bowl attached above the top suggests that the statue may actually be a desktop fountain or water installation.

The thematic connection to Captain Kirk is probably that the most famous classical dolphin-riding youth is the Greco-Roman god of romantic love, Eros/Cupid.  This Roman mosaic is a nice example.

[image: Roman mosaic]

Lots more examples, of Cupid and other classical dolphin riders, [can be found here](https://eidolon.pub/dont-look-now-but-there-s-an-ancient-roman-depiction-of-a-dolphin-under-your-bed-780e50ce08d9).  It's not clear from the blurry picture in the question, but the shadows on the tail of the dolphin, above the boy's shoulders, might actually be Cupid's small wings.

Comment: The motif of a boy riding on a dolphin is based on real life examples.

Comment: I could swear it was a boy being uplifted by an elephant's trunk. That's where my searches were going, anyway.